# How to pass and update data in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a TinyMCE.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This will be Editor JS</p>
    <div name="editor">
      <Editor
        api-key=""
        :init="{
          plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount'
        }"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// FIXME HIDE THE API KEY
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
const props = defineProps({
  text: String
})
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

and i want to use it in TestComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="h-sceen flex w-screen flex-col items-center justify-center gap-5">
    <div>hello from test</div>
    <div class="h-[300px] w-[300px]">
      <TinyMCE></TinyMCE>
      <div
        text="text"
        name="result"
        class="flex h-[300px] w-[300px] items-center justify-center border-2 border-black"
        v-html="text"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import TinyMCE from './TinyMCE.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
const text = ref('')
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

I want to be able to enter text in TinyMCE component and then use it in parent component where i have access to modified text. I tried using props but i am clearly doing something wrong.

i tried do it through props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`v-model`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html), or commonly known as *two-way props binding*. The principle is that, rather than keeping a ref in the child component, you keep a [writable computed value](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed). The `get` function returns the props and the `set` function emits an event with the new value.

```js
const props = defineProps({
  text: String
})

const textModel = computed({
  get() {
    return props.value.test
  },
  set(value) {
    emit("update:text", value);
  }
})
```

This way, when the child component wants to retrieve the text value, it's fetched from the props, and when it wants to mutate it, it emits an event with the updated value.

Then, in your parent component, you can add a props `text` prefixed with `v-model:`, which indicate to view that this value is going to be mutated from the event `update:text`.

```html
<template>
  <TinyMCE v-model:text="text" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const text = ref("")
</script>
```

This allow you to keep the reference to the `text` variable in your test component, but update it in your `TinyMCE` component.

You could, also, leave out the `v-model` prefix and use a props and an event listener:

```html
<template>
  <TinyMCE :text="text" @update:text="handleTextUpdate" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const text = ref("");

const handleTextUpdate = newValue => {
  text.value = newValue
}
</script>
```

Both works, but the `v-model` is shorter.

Comment: thanks sir for answer and for your time :)) but there are some bugs in this code 1. emit is not defined, so I added const emit= defineEmits() and it didnt work, but in general this code doesnt work, but thanks for the explanation

Comment: @user28273827332 did you pass the `update:text` event to the `defineEmits` function ?